# Run a java program from svn in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a job on Jenkins that runs the functional tests and generates test results. After i get results I need to run a new job that will trigger a java program from svn. What the program does it updated test results in bug tracking datebase. My question is how to setup a new job on Jenkins that will trigger java program? Do I need some kind script? All suggestions are welcome. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a job which checks out stuff from svn, like you would do for a job that does compilation.

Then create *Excecute Windows batch command* or *Execute shell* build step, where you put the command to run the java program, probably `java -jar ...`.